# 14:04 Why my USB Modem Huawei won't displayed as /dev/ttyUSB?

Tags: tty, huawei, asterisk

I want to use my modem huawei E153 like chan dongle for my Asterisk, but it is not show like TTYUSB see below the comand `dmesg | tail` when I put in USB port

```
  [ 2861.972140] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
  [ 2862.101090] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14fe
  [ 2862.101093] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
  [ 2862.101095] usb 1-2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
  [ 2862.101096] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
  [ 2862.102765] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
  [ 2862.102843] scsi host25: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
  [ 2862.102954] usb-storage 1-2:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
  [ 2862.103026] scsi host26: usb-storage 1-2:1.1
  [ 2862.858815] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 18
```

And see what happened some seconds after using same command `dmesg | tail`

```
     [ 6972.009232] sr 61:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
     [ 6972.009365] sr 61:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
     [ 6972.009456] sr 61:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
     [ 6972.009714] sd 62:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
     [ 6972.011393] sd 62:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
     [ 6972.019659] systemd-udevd[12215]: failed to execute '/usr/local/Arnet/driver/HWActivator' '/usr/local/Arnet/driver/HWActivator .bin': No such file or directory
     [ 6972.020060] systemd-udevd[12218]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/modem-modeswitch' '/lib/udev/modem-modeswitch --vendor 0x12d1 --product 0x14ac --typeoption-zerocd': No such file or directory
     [ 6972.053924] systemd-udevd[12236]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/modem-modeswitch' '/lib/udev/modem-modeswitch --vendor 0x12d1 --product 0x14ac --typeoption-zerocd': No such file or directory
     [ 6972.138654] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
     [ 6972.139266] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
```

And in my `/dev` it appear like `huawei_mobile` not TTYUSB instead.

I just founded in `/sys/class/tty` directory when I use `find -name "ttyUSB0"`

In my /dev/ not show it, please see below:

```
         root@vitor-pc:/dev# ls
         ati              mcelog              shm       tty42      ttyS24
         autofs           media0              snapshot  tty43      ttyS25
         block            mei0                snd       tty44      ttyS26
         bsg              mem                 sr0       tty45      ttyS27
         btrfs-control    memory_bandwidth    stderr    tty46      ttyS28
         bus              net                 stdin     tty47      ttyS29
         cdrom            network_latency     stdout    tty48      ttyS3
         char             network_throughput  tty       tty49      ttyS30
         console          null                tty0      tty5       ttyS31
         core             port                tty1      tty50      ttyS4
         cpu              ppp                 tty10     tty51      ttyS5
         cpu_dma_latency  psaux               tty11     tty52      ttyS6
         cuse             ptmx                tty12     tty53      ttyS7
         dahdi            pts                 tty13     tty54      ttyS8
         disk             ram0                tty14     tty55      ttyS9
         dri              ram1                tty15     tty56      uhid
         ecryptfs         ram10               tty16     tty57      uinput
         fb0              ram11               tty17     tty58      urandom
         fd               ram12               tty18     tty59      v4l
         full             ram13               tty19     tty6       vboxdrv
         fuse             ram14               tty2      tty60      vboxdrvu
         hidraw0          ram15               tty20     tty61      vboxnetctl
         hidraw1          ram2                tty21     tty62      vboxusb
         hpet             ram3                tty22     tty63      vcs
         i2c-0            ram4                tty23     tty7       vcs1
         i2c-1            ram5                tty24     tty8       vcs2
         i2c-2            ram6                tty25     tty9       vcs3
         i2c-3            ram7                tty26     ttyprintk  vcs4
         i2c-4            ram8                tty27     ttyS0      vcs5
         i2c-5            ram9                tty28     ttyS1      vcs6
         i2c-6            random              tty29     ttyS10     vcs8
         input            rfkill              tty3      ttyS11     vcsa
         kmsg             rtc                 tty30     ttyS12     vcsa1
         kvm              rtc0                tty31     ttyS13     vcsa2
         log              sda                 tty32     ttyS14     vcsa3
         loop0            sda1                tty33     ttyS15     vcsa4
         loop1            sda2                tty34     ttyS16     vcsa5
         loop2            sda3                tty35     ttyS17     vcsa6
         loop3            sda4                tty36     ttyS18     vcsa8
         loop4            sda5                tty37     ttyS19     vfio
         loop5            sda6                tty38     ttyS2      vga_arbiter
         loop6            sdb                 tty39     ttyS20     vhci
         loop7            sg0                 tty4      ttyS21     vhost-net
         loop-control     sg1                 tty40     ttyS22     video0
         mapper           sg2                 tty41     ttyS23     zero
```

When I use `lsusb` my Huawei is there

```
      root@vitor-pc:/dev# lsusb 
      Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
      Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
      Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
      Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1bcf:2b8a Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
      Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
      Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
      Bus 001 Device 023: ID 12d1:14ac Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
      Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. 
      Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Someone know how can I fix it?

Thanks very much.

Comment: The 3G modem in linux most of the time uses user space drivers. This is the reason why you are not seeing those ttyUSB0 device nodes. You should read how to setup modeswitch for your specific device and it will work easily. As per my knowledge some config files may be needed where we need to add our USB VID/PID values.